# An urn consists $3$ white, $4$ red,and $5$ black balls. Two balls are drawn without replacement . What is the probability that at least

Tags: combinatorics

An urn consists $3$ white, $4$ red and $5$ black balls. Two balls are drawn one by one without replacement. What is the probability that at least one ball is black?

My solution goes like this:

> We have $3$ white ,$4$ red and $5 $ black balls in the urn . The number of ways of choosing at least one black ball is $4\choose 1$$5\choose 1$$+$$5\choose 1$$3\choose 1$$+$$5\choose 2$. The number of ways of choosing two balls is $52\choose 2$. So the required probability is $($ $4\choose 1$$5\choose 1$$+$$5\choose 1$$3\choose 1$$+$$5\choose 2$$)$$/$$52\choose 2$.

The answer however given is $15/22$. But the order in which the balls are drawn is impertinent indeed . So what's the problem with this solution?Where is the problem occuring? I am not quite getting it?

Comment: What's with $\binom{52}{2}$?

Comment: Your work is fine, once you correct the number of ways of choosing two balls.

Comment: @JMP that was a typo ...sorry ...but I have fixed it anyways  ...Thank you!

Comment: If you substitute $\binom{12}{2}$ in place of $\binom{52}{2}$ in the denominator, then you get $\frac{45}{66} = \frac{15}{22}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the probability of **not** getting a black ball, which is
$$1-\frac{7}{12}\frac{6}{11}=\frac{15}{22}$$

In your post, $\binom{52}{2}$ should be replaced with $\binom{12}{2}$, and you get the right answer.